# Fixing wrong JSON data

Tags: c++, json, algorithm, qt, serialization

I'm working with a JSON data that I download from web. Problem with this JSON is that it's contents are incorrect. To show the problem here is a simplified preview:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "adsad"
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "aawew"
  }
]
```

So there is an array of these items, where in some value for "id" is string and somewhere it is an integer. This is the data that I get and I can't make the source fix this.

The solution I came up with was to fix this data before serializing it and here is my naive algorithm where `Defaults::intTypes()` is a vector of all key that should be integer but are sometimes string:

```
void fixJSONData(QString& data) {
    qDebug() << "Fixing JSON data ( thread: " << QThread::currentThreadId() << ")";
    QElapsedTimer timer;
    timer.start();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        for (const auto& key : Defaults::intTypes()) {
            if (data.mid(i, key.size() + 3) == "\"" + key + "\":") {
                int newLine = i + key.size() + 3;

                while (data[newLine] != ',' && data[newLine] != '}') {
                    if (data[newLine] == '"') {
                        data.remove(newLine, 1);
                    } else {
                        ++newLine;
                    }
                }

                i = newLine;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    qDebug() << "Fixing done in " << timer.elapsed() << " ms.";
}
```

Well it does fix the problem, but the algorithm is too slow and it is too slow (went through 4.5 million characters in 390 seconds). How could this be done faster?

P.S.: for JSON serialization I use [nlohmann::json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) library.

**Edit:** After reading up a bit deeper into JSON rules, it looks like that example above is absolutely valid JSON file. Should this be an issue related to C++ being strongly type dependent so it can't serialize an array of different elements into C++ classes?

**Edit2:** What I would like to create from that json string is `QVector<Model>` where:

```
class Model {
    unsigned id;
    QString name;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with that JSON file, exactly? `nlohmann::json::parse` seems to process your example correctly.

Comment: Your algorithm needlessly looks at almost every character of almost every line once for each entry in `Defaults::intTypes()`. If you're going to bake in the assumption that no more than one field name is in a line, you should process each line once to extract the field name, if any, and see if it's in the set of integer types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there must be several way to improve this conversion maybe there is a much more effective solution.

Most of the JSON libraries allow the end user to define custom serializer/deserializer for an object. If you create a custom deserializer then it can parse the original data and you don't have to modify the stream or files.

It's not only faster but also more elegant.

(If the given JSON library doesn't support custom deserialization I would consider choosing an other one.)

Comment: I have custom serialization/deserialization function already. The problem is in that when trying to create my model class from nlohmann::json I don't know how to deal with that the value for one key can be 2 different types

Comment: @MarošBeťko You can use `json::get<int>()` to retrieve the value of a node as an integer. In any case, it should be done during deserialization, not before parsing.

Comment: I can't because when it gets to "id": "123" it throw's error that an integer was expected.

Comment: I don't know this particular JSON library, but usually there is a function for checking if the node is String/number/object/array. Check the type first then read it as a String and convert to int if needed. Worst case scenario: handle the error and read again as a String.

Comment: I found the `is_string()` method and with it was able to either `std::stoi` the string to int or just read the int inside the custom deserialization function to my type. Thanks for the suggestion.